# Is this simple proof about symmetric sums correct?

Tags: inequality, fake-proofs

I'm asked to prove 
$$x \gt 0, y \gt 0, z  \gt 0 \rightarrow$$
$$\left(\frac{x+y}{x+y+z}\right)^\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{x+z}{x+y+z}\right)^\frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{y+z}{x+y+z}\right)^\frac{1}{2} \le 6^\frac{1}{2}$$

I rewrite the summands and say that it is sufficient to prove:
$$A^\frac{1}{2} + B^\frac{1}{2} + C^\frac{1}{2} \le 6^\frac{1}{2} $$ 
$$ A +B +C = 2$$
$$ 0 \lt A, B, C \le 1$$

Now I just square both sides to get:
$$A + (AB)^\frac{1}{2} + (AC)^\frac{1}{2} + B + (BC)^\frac{1}{2} + C \le 6$$

This seems simple:
$$2  + (AB)^\frac{1}{2} + (AC)^\frac{1}{2} + (BC)^\frac{1}{2} \le$$ 
$$ 2  + 1 + 1 + 1 \le 5 \le 6$$

So I ended up proving that the original bounds were too loose. That makes me worry that I messed up my proof somewhere.

Comment: Your expression for the square of $A^{1/2}+B^{1/2}+C^{1/2}$ is not correct.

Comment: You made a mistake when squaring.

Comment: $(A^{\frac12}+B^{\frac12}+C^{\frac12})^2=A+B+C+2(\sqrt{AB}+\sqrt{AC}+\sqrt{BC})$

Comment: Oh I see it now. I will have to think of a different proof then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.  Squaring both sides yields $$A+B+C+2(AB)^{1/2}+2(BC)^{1/2}+2(CA)^{1/2}\leq 6,$$ and so you only need to prove that $$(AB)^{1/2}+(BC)^{1/2}+(CA)^{1/2}\leq 2.$$  This inequality follows directly from the fact that $A+B+C=2$ along with Cauchy Schwarz.

**Alternative Solution:** Before squaring both sides, we can deduce desired inequality directly using Cauchy Schwarz.  We have that $$\left(A^{1/2}+B^{1/2}+C^{1/2}\right)^2\leq (A+B+C)(1+1+1),$$ and so we see that $$A^{1/2}+B^{1/2}+C^{1/2}\leq 6^{1/2}.$$

Comment: I understand your alternative solution, but can you elaborate on the use of Cauchy Schwarz in main solution?

Comment: The vectors <A^.5, B^.5, C^.5> and <B^.5, C^.5, A^.5> will work to complete the proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use Lagrange multipliers. With $A$, $B$, and $C$ as you chose, the minimum value of $f(A,B,C) = \sqrt{A} + \sqrt{B} + \sqrt{C}$ subject to the constraint $A+B+C=2$ must occur at a local minimum of $F(A,B,C,\lambda) = \sqrt{A} + \sqrt{B} + \sqrt{C} + \lambda (A+B+C-2)$.

This can only occur if ${\partial{F}\over\partial{A}}$, ${\partial{F}\over\partial{B}}$, and ${\partial{F}\over\partial{C}}$ are simultaneously zero. Calculating the derivatives, we get $${1\over{2\sqrt{A}}}+\lambda={1\over{2\sqrt{B}}}+\lambda={1\over{2\sqrt{C}}}+\lambda=0\textrm{,}$$ which implies that $A=B=C$. Using the fact that $A+B+C=2$, it follows that $A=B=C={2\over3}$. The minimum value of $\sqrt{A} + \sqrt{B} + \sqrt{C}$ is then $3\sqrt{2\over3}$, which equals $\sqrt6$.